# How to download all video from a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html page where I added 10 videos. When I click one video it starts downloading. But now I want to download all the videos when the user clicks the download all link . Like google or one drive.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/videos/video1.mov" target="_blank" class="document">Video 1</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/videos/video2.mov" target="_blank" class="document">Video 2</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/videos/" target="_blank">Download All</a>
```

Comment: Put them in a .zip file and link to `videos/all.zip`?

Comment: That's take some extra space.Can i grab all video and convert them into zip folder (client site) ?

Comment: Maybe [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/). It appears straightforward after looking over some [examples](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple compresses the video to `.zip` file as `@NiettheDarkAbsol`'s comment above.

Image:

[image]

My example:

```
<a href="https://support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT1425/sample_iTunes.mov.zip">Download now</a>

<script>
  $('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent redirecting to the location
    window.href.location = 'https://support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT1425/sample_iTunes.mov.zip'
  })
</script>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create iframes when a user click on the **Download All** button.
Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/7xxq08mo/.

```
<iframe style="display:none;" src="https://s3-us-west-  2.amazonaws.com/coverr/webm/One-Swan.webm">swan</iframe>
<iframe style="display:none" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/coverr/mp4/Drink-Wine.mp4">wine</iframe>
```